# Lazily partition a sequence into differently-sized chunks in Clojure

Tags: clojure, partitioning

How to lazily partition a sequence into differently-sized chunks in Clojure? Sort of like `(partition n xs)`, but for a sequence of `ns`. For example:

```
(chunker [3 4 5] (range 12))
=> ((0 1 2) (3 4 5 6) (7 8 9 10 11))
```

Answer (score 3):

I needed this to chunk some inputs and didn't want to use Instaparse. Here is a lazy solution that supports cycled chunk sizes:

```
(defn chunker
  "Like (partition N input) but for a sequence of Ns."
  [[chunk & chunks] coll]
  (lazy-seq
    (when-let [s (seq coll)]
      (cons (take chunk s)
        (when chunks (chunker chunks (drop chunk s)))))))
```

### Usage

```
(chunker [3 4 5] (range 20))
=> ((0 1 2) (3 4 5 6) (7 8 9 10 11)) ;; note not input not fully consumed.

(chunker (cycle [3 4 5]) (range 20))
=> ((0 1 2) (3 4 5 6) (7 8 9 10 11) (12 13 14) (15 16 17 18) (19))
```

Comment: This is about how I would write it, but you're a bit more eager than necessary. The `lazy-seq` should be at the top level, not inside the `cons` call: you shouldn't consume any of the input if nobody asks for an element. You're also too eager on the list of chunks, but that's less of a big deal because those are probably just a vector of ints most of the time.

Comment: @amalloy refer to the implemenation of `clojure.core/iterate`.

Comment: `iterate` doesn't consume another input sequence, so it doesn't need to be lazy for the first item. Also, in recent versions `iterate` isn't implemented in Clojure at all, but in Java, so there's not much to compare to. You should compare to `map` instead.

Comment: Thanks, @amalloy! You are right. Fixed. Previous version was eager even if no input is requested.

Comment: This behaves like `partition-all`, not like `partition`. For example, `(chunker [10] (range 3)) => ((0 1 2))`. But this is probably what's wanted.